# Raster image vectorization

Tags: c#, .net

I need help, I have to create an application that converts raster image to vector. (Just application of two PictureBox, to the left to load a simple bitmap image and the right should be created - vector)

I need help in finding some vektorizačných algorithms. I do not know anything even googled.
Please help if anyone has experience with similar problems. Mainly that it was in C #.
thank you

(Sorry for my English :) )

---

This is a very simple images. 
for example

http://img825.imageshack.us/img825/4139/22536687.png

---

Edited

ok, first detect edges, for example - Canny edge detection, how can I create vectors?

Answer (score 0):

Not every image can be easily converted to a vector image, for instance, some pictures taken by camera. There is **no**, I believe, **single algorithm that can convert all bmp to vector one**. The most viable solution is to take a look and analysis at your sample image, capture its unique features, and propose a **targeted** algorithm for this specific type of images.

You might consider using thresholding or other image segmentation approaches to isolate the background and foreground, then doing some smoothing etc. to get the silhouettes. Trying your algorithm in Matlab would be a good idea, it is easier to get it done on a trial-n-error basis.